# How to run a .py file in Ipython?

Tags: python, windows, ipython, argparse

## Python and Ipython versions:

1. The version of the notebook server is `3.0.0-f75fda4`.
2. Python `2.7.9` |Anaconda `2.2.0` (64-bit)|

## Problem description

I am using the `undaqtools` module in Python. The package page is [here](http://pythonhosted.org/undaqTools/). This package contains the functions to convert a data acquisition file (DAQ) from a driving simulator output to HDF5 format. There are 2 ways to do so according to the package page. One way is to convert files one by one by using the functions `daq.read` and `daq.write_hd5`. I have used this several times and it works flawlessly. The second method is to use the script `undaq.py` to batch convert many DAQ files simultaneously. This script is located in `/Anaconda/Scripts/` in C drive (Windows 7). I have 3 DAQ files in the `DrivingSimulator/Data` folder, named:

1. Cars_20160601_01
2. Cars_20160601_02
3. Cars_20160601_03

So, I first changed directory to `DrivingSimulator/Data`. Then according to the [Getting Started](http://pythonhosted.org/undaqTools/gettingstarted.html) page of the package, tried the `undaq.py *` command in IPython, which gave error:

```
%run C:/Users/durraniu/Anaconda/Scripts/undaq.py *
usage: undaq.py [-h] [-n NUMCPU] [-o OUTTYPE] [-e ELEMFILE] [-r] [-d] path
undaq.py: error: unrecognized arguments: Cars_20160601_02.daq Cars_20160601_03.daq
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2
```

Here is the full traceback:

```
%tb
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SystemExit                                Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\durraniu\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, glob, loc, compiler)
    205                 filename = fname
    206             compiler = compiler or compile
--> 207             exec(compiler(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
    208 
    209     else:

C:\Users\durraniu\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\undaqtools-0.2.3-py2.7.egg\EGG-INFO\scripts\undaq.py in <module>()
      2 # EASY-INSTALL-SCRIPT: 'undaqtools==0.2.3','undaq.py'
      3 __requires__ = 'undaqtools==0.2.3'
----> 4 __import__('pkg_resources').run_script('undaqtools==0.2.3', 'undaq.py')

C:\Users\durraniu\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\setuptools-18.4-py2.7.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py in run_script(self, requires, script_name)
    733         ns.clear()
    734         ns['__name__'] = name
--> 735         self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
    736 
    737     def __iter__(self):

C:\Users\durraniu\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\setuptools-18.4-py2.7.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py in run_script(self, script_name, namespace)
   1657             )
   1658             script_code = compile(script_text, script_filename,'exec')
-> 1659             exec(script_code, namespace, namespace)
   1660 
   1661     def _has(self, path):

C:\Users\durraniu\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\undaqtools-0.2.3-py2.7.egg\EGG-INFO\scripts\undaq.py in <module>()

C:\Users\durraniu\Anaconda\lib\argparse.pyc in parse_args(self, args, namespace)
   1702         if argv:
   1703             msg = _('unrecognized arguments: %s')
-> 1704             self.error(msg % ' '.join(argv))
   1705         return args
   1706 

C:\Users\durraniu\Anaconda\lib\argparse.pyc in error(self, message)
   2372         """
   2373         self.print_usage(_sys.stderr)
-> 2374         self.exit(2, _('%s: error: %s\n') % (self.prog, message))

C:\Users\durraniu\Anaconda\lib\argparse.pyc in exit(self, status, message)
   2360         if message:
   2361             self._print_message(message, _sys.stderr)
-> 2362         _sys.exit(status)
   2363 
   2364     def error(self, message):

SystemExit: 2
```

I can't understand this error. Also, I tried using `undaq.py` in CMD but that opened a new window saying that Windows can't open this file:

[image]

Please let me know what am I doing wrong? Also, please note that the path to `Script` folder and Python is already in the PATH variable of system variables.

## UPDATE:

Following the instructions of @hpaulj, I did following:

```
## Changing to the directory containing DAQ files:
%cd C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/DrivingSimulator/Data

## Running the undaq.py script:
%run C:/Users/durraniu/Anaconda/Scripts/undaq.py -r -d \\*
```

This gave me following output:

```
Glob Summary
--------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                              hdf5
daq                                            size (KB)      exists
--------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------


debug = True
rebuild = True

Converting daqs with 1 cpus (this may take awhile)...


Debug Summary

Batch processing completed.

--------------------------------------------------------------------
Conversion Summary
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Total elapsed time: 0.1 s
Data converted: 0.000 MB
Data throughput: 0.0 MB/s
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It seems that the script can't 'see' any files in the Data directory. I tried the same in cmd with the prefix `python` and it gave the same result. How can I fix this?
For your reference, I am pasting the contents of `undaq.py` file here:

```
#!C:\Users\durraniu\Anaconda\python.exe
# EASY-INSTALL-SCRIPT: 'undaqtools==0.2.3','undaq.py'
__requires__ = 'undaqtools==0.2.3'
__import__('pkg_resources').run_script('undaqtools==0.2.3', 'undaq.py')
```

Please note that I have the version 0.2.3 of undaqtools installed.

## UPDATE 2

I have also tried following in Ipython:

```
%run -G C:/Users/durraniu/Anaconda/Scripts/undaq.py -r -d *
```

This gives a recurring error:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a simple script, `echo_argv.py`:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

Running it in Ipython with your commandline:

```
In [1222]: %run echo_argv *
['echo_argv.py', 'stack38002264.py', 'stack37714032.py', 'test', 'stack37930737.py ...]
```

shows that it gets the full directory listing in `sys.argv`.

Your first error is produced by the commandline parser of `undaq.py` (hence the `argparse` error stack).

```
usage: undaq.py [-h] [-n NUMCPU] [-o OUTTYPE] [-e ELEMFILE] [-r] [-d] path
undaq.py: error: unrecognized arguments: Cars_20160601_02.daq Cars_20160601_03.daq
```

This message tells me that `undaq` expects one `path` argument, which was met by the first file name: '160601_02.daq'.  The other file names are thus superfluous, and it is complaining.

I suspect it will run better if you give it just one file name, or the current directory name, something like:

```
%run undaq.py .
%run undaq.py Cars_20160601_01.daq
```

I expect you'd get the same error if in CMD you did

```
python undaq.py *
```

I don't understand why the 1`getting started` page recommends using `*` when the commandline parser gives this error message.  I'm wondering if there's a version difference - the documentation page is for a different version.

Consider doing

```
python undaq.py -h
%run undaq.py -h
```

to get a fuller help message.

https://github.com/rogerlew/undaqTools/blob/master/undaqTools/scripts/undaq.py

Looking at this code, the `argparse` definition for the `path` argument is

```
parser.add_argument('path', type=str, help='Path for glob             ("*")')
```

That suggests that the correct call is to quote `'*'` so it is passed as is to the script, rather than being evaluated by the shell

```
python undaq.py '*'
```

However I'm having trouble getting the same behavior with `%run`.

`undaq.py` does its own `glob`, so it wants a path string, not the full list generated by the shell `glob`.

Here's what `%run` says about globing:

```
Arguments are expanded using shell-like glob match.  Patterns
'*', '?', '[seq]' and '[!seq]' can be used.  Additionally,
tilde '~' will be expanded into user's home directory.  Unlike
real shells, quotation does not suppress expansions.  Use
*two* back slashes (e.g. ``\\*``) to suppress expansions.
To completely disable these expansions, you can use -G flag.
```

So I need to do:

```
In [1236]: %run echo_argv \\*
['echo_argv.py', '*']
In [1237]: %run -G echo_argv *
['echo_argv.py', '*']
```

Comment: I tried running `python undaq.py '*'` but it throws error: `python: can't open file 'undaq.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: That error indicates that `undaq.py` is not in the current directory.  Have you run `python` and `ipython` code before?

Comment: undaq.py script file is in the Anaconda/Scripts/ folder. And yes, I have run Ipython code before but never ran a .py script file before. I am confused, what should I do next to resolve this problem? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be running `undaq` in ipython. It is a stand-alone script.

To run a python program you need to use the python interpreter. A typical installation of python associates .py files with the python interpreter. However it seems that on your system this hasn't happened.

Check that you have python installed by running `python` at a command line prompt (you should get some information about the version of python, and the `>>>` prompt). Quit from python and then type:

```
python undaq.py *
```

This loads the python interpreter and tells it to read and execute the command in the file `undaq.py` passing all the files in the current directory as arguments.

Comment: python is installed in my system. I checked again by typing python and it did show the `>>>` prompt. But once I type `python undaq.py *` in the `DrivingSimulator/Data` directory, it gives error: `python: can't open file 'undaq.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: @umairdurrani you need to execute `python path\to\undaq.py *` *or* alternatively go to the place where `undaq.py` is and run `python undaq.py path\to\DrivingSimulator\Data\*`